# $x$-value of $(+)$ meeting point of unit circle and $y=x^2$

Tags: calculus

A circle of radius $1$ centered at $(0,0)$, and $y=x^2$. What is the $x$-value of their meeting point in Quadrant I?

I thought about using trig to solve this, but failed to make much progress doing that.

Any hints?

Comment: Do you know the equation of a circle of radius $1$? If so, it is algebra

Comment: what, sqrt(1-x^2)? I tried that w.o getting answer desired. I may be misunderstanding the question.

Comment: No trig, you want a polynomial equation for the circle, not one involving radicals.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $$x^2+y^2=1$$
$$y=x^2$$

Where do they intersect?

Comment: Am I reading the Q wrong: Draw a circle of radius 1 resting in the parabola y =x^2. The distance
to (a, a2) equals the radius 1 when a = _. This
locates the touching point.

Comment: The $(x,y)$ have to be chosen, such that both equations are equal. $x^2 + y^2 - 1 = x^2 - y$

Answer (score 1):

A unit circle will have the equation $$x^2 + y^2=1$$
To find the intersection points of this with the parabola $y=x^2$ we substitute the value of $y$.
We can write this as
$$x^2 + x^4=1$$
This is a quadratic equation in terms of $x^2$. 
We can now write $$x^2=\frac{-1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$$ 
Note that a real number squared cannot be negative. 
$$x=\pm\sqrt{\frac{-1+\sqrt{5}}{2}}$$
The negative solution will be eliminated as it will not be in first quadrant. Hence,
$$x=\sqrt{\frac{-1+\sqrt{5}}{2}}$$

Comment: Looks good, but I would have went the other way of subbing in, $y+y^2=1$(personal choice of course, but it looks nicer to new students)

Comment: I went with $x$ because this way we'd get the value of $x$ straight away. But yeah, like you said, it just personal choice.

Comment: $\color{green}{\checkmark}\quad\quad\text{(+1)}$ from me.

Comment: Thanks. Returned the favour :D

Comment: Looking for the answer sqrt(3)/2. Any clue?

Comment: @Chas $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$ is not the correct answer.

Comment: @AvZ: did you see the original question in my comment to CtaC's answer? I wonder if I read it wrong somehow. This question has puzzled me for a while.

Comment: @Chas I think the question is different to what you asked. Because in this case, the parabola cuts the circle instead of touching it. The original question might have been asking you to find the centre of the circle so that it touches it and fulfills your second condition

Comment: @AvZ - could that be something like at what value a are the tangent lines for $y = x^2$ and $y=-\sqrt{1-x^2}$ the same?

Comment: @Chas Possibly,but I cannot be too sure unless you can give the question in its original language.

Comment: Draw a circle of radius 1 resting in the parabola $y=x^2$.
At the touching point (a, a2), the equation of the normal line is __. That line has x = 0 when y =_. The distance
to (a, a2) equals the radius 1 when a = _. This
locates the touching point.

Comment: @Avz - curious if you had a chance to look at the problem?